# Trying to prove this inequality involving exponential function

Tags: calculus, integration

Given :

1. A continuous non-negative function $f(x)$ on $\mathbb R^{+} \cup \{ 0\}$
2. $\alpha > 0$
3. $h(x) = \displaystyle \int \limits_0^x f(u) du + \alpha$
4. $\forall x$, $f \leq h$

To prove : $$f(x) \leq \alpha e^x$$

Attempt :

$$\dfrac {d}{dx} [\ln h(x)] = \dfrac {h'(x)}{h(x)}$$

By the fundamental theorem of integral calculus, $h'(x) = f(x)$ and $\therefore $

$$\dfrac {d}{dx} [\ln h(x)] = \dfrac {f(x)}{h(x)}$$

From the 4th given point, $f \leq h$,

$$\dfrac {d}{dx} [\ln h(x)] \leq 1$$

i.e. the function $\ln [h(x)]$ never grows faster than the linear function, with slope 1.

From this step, I wrote $$\ln [h(x)] \leq x + C, \text{ for some } C$$

**Is the above step correct?**

$$\therefore h(x) \leq e^{x+C} = e^C e^x = B e^x$$

$$\therefore f(x) \leq h(x) \leq B e^x$$

Also, am unable to get in $\alpha$ in this inequality.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a consequence of Grönwall's inequality, see for instance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality.

In your case, you can take $u(x) = h(x)$, $b(x) = f(x)/h(x) > 0$. Your condition then becomes:
\begin{equation}
u(x) = \alpha +  \int_{0}^{x} b(s)u(s)ds.
\end{equation}
By your first three assumptions,  $\alpha$ is positive and non-decreasing, $b$ is continuous and non-negative. Therefore, Grönwall's inequality yields:
\begin{equation}
u(x) \leq \alpha \exp \left( \int_{0}^{x} b(s)ds \right). 
\end{equation}
By your final assumption, $b(s)\leq 1$,  which yields the inequality you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Your strategy is a good one. Since $\ln h(x)\le x+\ln h(0)$, $h(x)\le h(0)e^x$. But $h(0)=\alpha$.